# Is there any method to sieve all the object out of a List?

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Account>` with a bunch of subclass from `Account` like `Admin` or `User`. Is there any method to sieve all the `User` out?

Comment: Use linq and try the `where` extension method.

Comment: [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: To add to what Damien said. Usage would be something like `var admins = accounts.OfType<Admin>().ToList();`

Comment: @Knoop Well the final `ToList` there is likely not needed.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry English is not my main language, I must have misinterpreted op in thinking they wanted something where the sieving was actually already done vs something that will sieve once asked (deferred excecution). But in general I just add the `ToList()` because I've seen way too much problems with the concept of not excecuting when called but you're right there is a good chance it's not needed in the actual case of op.

Comment: @Knoop Indeed, of course, there's also the problem that using `OfType` looks to be exactly the opposite of what OP is asking for here anyway. But it's not really clear.

Comment: @Gr4y Are you looking for a list of only `User` objects or a list that has everything except `User` objects?

Comment: @DavidG I'm looking for `User` in a List that have a lot of object like `Admin`, `User`, `Boss`, etc...

Comment: I solved it, thank to @Knoop. You guys are so good